# Ad Hoc Catalina 10.15.x Deployment without iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes, macos-catalina, ad-hoc-distribution

I know you can develop an IOS app and give it to registered devices for testing through Ad Hoc. Testers can physically install the app on their device with xcode or iTunes. Maco OS Catalina 10.15.x doesn't support iTunes as they decided more apps are simpler than one.

So if a tester doesn't have xcode, what do they use to deploy the app on their device for testing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the app I was looking for is "Apple Configurator 2". It is the iTunes replacement for managing devices and installing apps physically.

Quick instructions:

1 Open Apple Configurator 2 and plug in IOS device

2 Select the device

3 in the top menu select the "+" (Add) option

4 Select Apps > Choose from my Mac...

5 Find the .ipa file for your test app

Source: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devade83d1d7?sub=dev87a955931

Sorry, before I posted the question I was apparently looking at every recently outdated tutorial / help forum except the actual documentation.

Comment: That’s not necessary. You can drag the app into the device in the Finder.

Answer (score 0):

> So if a tester doesn't have xcode, what do they use to deploy the app on their device for testing?

The Finder.